# How to log both prevState and original state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a toggle switch that goes from true to false.

```
flipSwitch = () => {
    console.log(this.state)
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }))
  }
```

Everything is working like it is supposed to, but I want to log both the prevState and original state at the same time. I tried below adding a callback function after setting the prevState, but then it breaks my toggle switch.

```
flipSwitch = () => {
    console.log(this.state)
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }, () => console.log(prevState)))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not correct what you're trying to do at here

```
flipSwitch = () => {
    console.log(this.state)
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }, () => console.log(prevState)))
  }
```

You won't have access to `prevState` in 2nd parameter of setState.

You should modify your `setState` function like this

```
flipSwitch = () => {
    console.log(this.state) // this refers to previous state here
    this.setState(prevState => {
      console.log(prevState) // prevState refers to previous state
      return ({
        isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
      })
    }, () => console.log(this.state) // here this refers to updated state)
  }
```

E.g you can try

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isToggleOn: false
    };
  }
  flipSwitch = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState(
      prevState => {
        console.log("prevState", prevState);
        return {
          isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
        };
      },
      () => {
        console.log("setState Callback", this.state);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.flipSwitch}>
          {this.state.isToggleOn ? "Flipped" : "Flip Switch!"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```